# Laravel make unique 16 character hash

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I want to make a completely unique hash that is 16 characters long to make a public link for certain private blog posts. So they can be accessed at:

> https://website.com/read/ASDFGHJ9827DYCO9

In Laravel there is a helper function that goes

```
\Hash::make($request->password);
```

It makes a hash like this:

```
$2y$10$kouytAixb/Yp5gpH7QqL6et/P.fW.qElsGkMncVM.1/29waEqeqjy
```

The trouble is that I want to make a hash that only uses letters and numbers and is 16 characters long and is absolutely unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Elmore's answer is correct, additionally, Hashing a number makes the value vulnerable to rainbow table attacks, so I would add some "salt" before the actual id, that is hard to guess, so that the rainbow tables are useless, ideally, of length 20 or more:

```
md5(salt . $model->id)
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't need to be secure (i.e. you don't care if someone can reverse it to get the original value), just `md5()` it. That'll return a 16-character hexadecimal string which is reasonably-well distributed.

```
md5($model->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two option. Not exactly 16 characters.

1. Generate random number with php `hash` function.

   `echo hash('ripemd128', 'some random input');
   // echo's hex represented 32byte of data`
2. Encrypt some content, For example `id` of the page. With symmetric encryption a `key` will be the unlock for that data. Uniqueness is not important anymore, How can it not be....

Explained in php doc, http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

```
//$key should have been previously generated in a cryptographically safe way, like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
```

You can look for list of ciphers with this method, http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php